# Do portfolio projects count as 'commercial use'

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I may be overthinking this bit but... I want to use a certain audio file with creative commons license, which [states](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/) that I may not use it for commercial purposes.

Hence the question: do portfolio projects (which may indirectly give me income if I get a project/job because of it) considered commercial use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're using something to advertise your business, that is a commercial use, as compared to a "private use" such as your own amusement or education.